# replace an element depending on it's class (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, dom, replace, controller, directive

I am making a date picker.

```
<a ng-click="navbarlinksCtrl.clickedfr()" ng-class="{'active': navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageFr()}">FR </a>
<a ng-click="navbarlinksCtrl.clickeden()" ng-class="{'active': navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageEn()}">EN</a>
```

Here, the `<a>` takes the active class if this is the current language, and I would like to change the active element into a `<span>`.

I tried some ways, but anything worked ($window.element, replaceWith, GetElementsByClassName, but doesn't works :/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<span ng-if="navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageFr()" ng-class="{'active': navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageFr()}">FR</span>
<span ng-if="navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageEn()" ng-class="{'active': navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageEn()}">EN</span>
<a ng-if="!navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageFr()" ng-click="navbarlinksCtrl.clickedfr()" ng-class="{'active': navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageFr()}">FR</a>
<a ng-if="!navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageEn()" ng-click="navbarlinksCtrl.clickeden()" ng-class="{'active': navbarlinksCtrl.checkLanguageEn()}">EN</a>
```